# Unknown Filetype in ls

Tags: linux, files, ls, file-types

In general, what are the reasons why a filetype might show as unknown (`?`) in `ls` output?

See the first bit for the file `/sbin/start-stop-daemon`, which should indicate `-` for "regular file", instead is displayed as `?` for "unknown".

```
ts7500:~# ls -alh /sbin/s*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  52K Apr 29  2008 /sbin/sfdisk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  875 Dec  6  2009 /sbin/shadowconfig
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  12K Apr 19  2010 /sbin/showmount
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  18K Aug 12  2008 /sbin/shutdown
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  28K Nov 16  2008 /sbin/slattach
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  12K Apr 19  2010 /sbin/sm-notify
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  58K Jul 27  2008 /sbin/ss
?rwsrwsrwt 1 65535 root 4.0G Dec 31  1969 /sbin/start-stop-daemon
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  19K Aug 12  2008 /sbin/startpar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root 9.8K Aug 12  2008 /sbin/sulogin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root    6 Jun  9  2011 /sbin/swapoff -> swapon
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  17K Apr 29  2008 /sbin/swapon
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  11K Aug  6  2009 /sbin/sysctl
```

Comment: Looks like a corrupt file system to me. (4.0G size, uid=65535, date=1969; every bit lit up like a Christmas tree.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that your `start-stop-daemon` is 4GB in size and dated Dec 31, 1969, I suspect your filesystem may be corrupted...

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

and then reboot to check your filesystem.

The question mark in `ls`'s output here comes from the [`filetype_letter` array](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n176) (in GNU `ls`):

```
/* Display letters and indicators for each filetype.
   Keep these in sync with enum filetype.  */
static char const filetype_letter[] = "?pcdb-lswd";
```

This corresponds to `C_ORPHAN`:

```
#define FILETYPE_INDICATORS                             \
  {                                                     \
    C_ORPHAN, C_FIFO, C_CHR, C_DIR, C_BLK, C_FILE,      \
    C_LINK, C_SOCK, C_FILE, C_DIR                       \
  }
```

and `unknown` in the `filetype` `enum`, and is [the default for a file of unknown type](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n4482):

```
          /* Classify a file of some other type as C_ORPHAN.  */
          type = C_ORPHAN;
```

(`ls` implementations are free to add their own characters to those [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html).)

Comment: Checking file systems...fsck 1.41.3 (12-Oct-2008)
done.

Comment: Thank you for a possible solution, though in my case I prefer to create a new root image. I was more curious about the reasons for the `?`.

Comment: Why is the time a hint? Is there something special about it? Do problematic files default to a second before the beginning of the epoch or something?

Comment: @terdon No, they default to the epoch exactly. Just that the epoch is displayed as 31 Dec 1969 in time zones west of Greenwich.

Comment: @ChrisMerck I've added the origin of the ?.

Comment: @terdon - I believe that the time **is** EPOCH, and the less hours are simply likely to be due to timezone.  Then: no times in the inode -> use EPOCH.  (that's still an educated guess though)

Comment: Given the 65535 owner and the 4GB (likely 4294967295) size - the timestamp may similarly be all ones. Since time_t is signed on linux, this gives Dec 31 1969.

Comment: any clue to why in the `FILETYPE_INDICATORS` we have twice `C_DIR` (corresponding both times to `d` in the `filetype_letter[]`) and twice `C_FILE` which corresponds first time with `-` and second time with `w` ??

Comment: @dave_alcarin The second `C_FILE` is used for [whiteouts](https://lwn.net/Articles/325369/), the second `C_DIR` is used for directories which are included in `ls`'s arguments (they need to be processed slightly differently).